# pyTest verify files are created correctly

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using the [Python docx package](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate Microsoft Word documents with a script that also incorporates some other calculations/math functions handled in Python/Pandas/Numpy, etc... that automatically get inputted into the Word Document report via Docx.

Is it possible to use pyTest to verify a different Python script is outputing a report properly? As I develop more complicated calculations even if I can verify the Microsoft Word document is being generated I know the script hasn't errored out so that would be useful to me that pyTest can verify the report generates okay. In time it would be nice that the calculations work in a specific manner as well but I am just trying to get setup with pyTest on something simple to begin with, any tips appreciated.

My project directory looks like this below with one report generating script named `fc1.py`:

```
fc1.py              → Python script with docx package to generate a Word Document
final_report        → Directory for the Word Document report output from fc1.py
reports             → Directory for an init.py
 └ init.py          → Python docx/Pandas methods to generate the report called from fc1.py
tests               → Directory for pyTest scripts
 └ fc1_test.py      → pyTest script that calls fc1.py and attempts to see if the Microsoft Word report is getting generated in the final_report directoy
```

My pyTest script looks like this below where I am attempting to just call `fc1.py` to run with an argument and then verify the output file exists when complete in the `final_report` directory.

```
import os
import pytest
import subprocess

# dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# pytest_args = os.path.join(dir_path,'fc1.py')

pytest_args = ['../fc1.py "Test Report"']
print(pytest_args)


def verify_if_file_exists():
    final_report_path = './final_report/"Test Report".docx'
    final_report_existing = os.path.exists(final_report_path)
    is_existing = os.path.exists(final_report_existing)

    # return boolean if report was generated
    return is_existing


def test_report_generated():
    assert generator() == True


def generator():
    pytest.main(pytest_args)
    return verify_if_file_exists()
```

Trying to run pyTest on Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\tests>pytest
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.13, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\bbartling\OneDrive - Slipstream\Desktop\pytester\tests
plugins: anyio-3.5.0
collected 1 item

fc1_test.py .                                                                                                    [100%]

================================================== 1 passed in 0.77s ==================================================
```

It is showing a successful test but I dont see the report being generated in the `final_report` directory, its empty... is there anything I am doing incorrect? Or does pytest generate some sort of virtual duplicate directories and files, so that's why I wouldn't see anything in my `final_report` directory as I were running the actual `fc1.py` file? Not alot of wisdom here any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. Specifically these two lines:

```
final_report_existing = os.path.exists(final_report_path)
is_existing = os.path.exists(final_report_existing)
```

`final_report_existing` is already returning a `boolean` so what ends up happening is `is_existing` ends up being:

```
os.path.exists(True)
# OR
os.path.exists(False)
```

The output of both of these function calls is `True`. That is why the test is succeeding no matter what. Change the function to be:

```
def verify_if_file_exists():
    final_report_path = './final_report/"Test Report".docx'
    final_report_existing = os.path.exists(final_report_path)

    # return boolean if report was generated
    return final_report_existing
```

Then for your test function all you need is:

```
def test_report_generated():
    assert generator()
```